# How can I speed up this SQL query that is timing out?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

Is there a better way to rewrite the code? The query takes forever to execute. Thanks

```
 SELECT * from w..ts
    where not si in
    (
    select si from g..sa
    )
    and ci in
    (
    Select ClientID from w..tcwhere ds= 'AZ'
    )
    and s> 2
    and sd between '1/1/2010' and GETDATE()
    order by si
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  PLease read [ask].  This is not a question.  What db platform, what specific error?

Comment: Are these actual web services? This is not enough information to give you any kind of useful response.

Comment: Is there a better way to rewrite the code the query takes forever to execute thanks

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your tables?  If not, that's where to start.  Take a look at http://use-the-index-luke.com for a tutorial on indexes.  If you do have indexes, then you need to show us the table and index definitions so we can tell if they're been created effectively.

Comment: Hopefully `ServiceDate` is an actual date/time type.... Oh, and please [don't use `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (because of the inclusive upper-bound, `<`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider joins or applies instead.

```
SELECT * from webservice..tService
left join table t1 on t1.col1 = tService.col2
inner join table t2 on t2.col1 = tService.col2
where t1.ServiceID is null
and ServiceStep > 2
and ServiceDate between '1/1/2010' and GETDATE()
order by ServiceID
```